# JQuery background color manipulation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, onclick

I am trying to use JQuery to change the background color of my page, by cycling through an array of colors, every time the button (with ID = "findOut") is clicked - but it does not seem to be working?

HTML (for the button):

```
    <div class = "mainContain">

        <button id = "findOut">
            <p>Click Me!</p>
        </button>

    </div>
```

JS/JQuery:

```
 $("document").ready(function(){

    var palette = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink", "orange"];
    var index = 0;
    var size = palette.length;

    $("#findOut").click(function(){
        document.body.style.background = pallete[index%size];
        index++;
    });

});
```

Comment: Just use `$(body).css('background-color', 'red');`.

Comment: I accidentally posted the wrong code, I just updated - please check again. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** After you edited the question and inserted the correct code the actual problem you have comes from your misspelling of `palette` as `pallete`.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

    var palette = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink", "orange"];
    var index = 0;
    var size = palette.length;

    $("#findOut").click(function() {
        document.body.style.background = palette[index % size];
        index++;
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContain">

    <button id="findOut">
            <p>Click Me!</p>
        </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Before OP's edit** :

You are actually assigning the same color `red` whenever you click on it. You'll have to choose a different color each time you click on it. Choose it from array by something like

```
palette[index % size]
```

You are already increment `index` take a remander with size of array to repeat when index increases the size of the array

And to make it consistent with `jQuery`, use `$("body").css('background-color','color')` to change color

**After edit** : 
You've a type in your code `pallete` should be `pallette`

```js
$("document").ready(function(){

    var palette = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink", "orange"];
    var index = 0;
    var size = palette.length;

    $("#findOut").click(function(){
      $("body").css('background-color', palette[index % size]);
       
        index++;
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "mainContain">

        <button id = "findOut">
            <p>Click Me!</p>
        </button>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$(body).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Or:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```